# How to approach integrated extended service and durable goods UCC SOF K

Tags: contract-law, terms-of-service, ucc

A and B are friends. A is a reputable retailer specializing in shoes. B asks A for economical help, and A agrees that if B can manufacture a custom shoe that they'd continue working together.

Some months later, B produces a prototype that A wants to buy in 2 lots (100 pairs of shoes). A and B want a contract that accomplishes two items:

- B is to continue building and manufacturing products exclusively to A for a period of 24 months,
- A is to purchase 2 lots (100 pairs) of B's initial shoe line for $10 each unit.

Is there a benefit of having a single document with an amendment clause or separate contracts?